# why aren't my slack client rtm messages showing in slack

Tags: python, python-2.7, slack, slack-api, collaboration

Hi I'm a using the python slack client library and I cannot work out why my messages are not showing up when using the

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

token = 'XXXXXXXX'  # my token
sc = SlackClient(token)
if sc.rtm_connect():  # connect to a Slack RTM websocket
    sc.rtm_send_message('general', 'I need coffee')
else:
print('Connection Failed, invalid token?')
```

My Bot is part of the public channel I am trying to send the message too, I don't receive any errors but nothing is showing up in the channel I'm sending it too. I have tried both the channel name and its id.

The following does work

```
import json
from slackclient import SlackClient


def list_channels():
    channels_call = slack_client.api_call("channels.list")
    if channels_call.get('ok'):
        return channels_call['channels']
    return None


def send_message(channel_id, message):
    slack_client.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
         channel=channel_id,
         text=message,
         username='mybot',
         icon_emoji=':robot_face:'
    )


slack_client = SlackClient('XXXXXXXXX')

channels = list_channels()
if channels:
    for c in channels:
        if c['name'] == 'general':
            send_message(c['id'], 'I need coffee.')
        else:
            print("Unable to authenticate.")
```

And I see the message come up almost instantly in my channel.

I have confirmed through both the slack website and the api that my bot is a member of this channel.

Am I missing something about the way this works?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your bot token instead of your user token. There 2 types of token in slack and if you want the bot to reply to the slack channel you should use bot token.

Comment: Thanks I am using my bot token in both cases

Comment: I am happy that this fixed your issue. :-)

Comment: I’m sorry I should have been clearer. I was already using the bot token in both cases and I have this problem. My issue is not fixed.